# Setting multiple and different attributes for columns of a data.table

Tags: r, attributes, data.table, attr

`data.table` has the elegant `setattr` for in-place addition of a single attribute to a column.  Is there an elegant way to overlay multiple attributes in one step?  For example, suppose that a `data.table` has many columns and I want to assign two attributes to column `x1` and three attributes to column `x3` as might be specified in the following `list`:

```
a <- list(x1=list(label='X1', units='mm'),
          x3=list(label='X3', comment='collected remotely', format='type 3'))
```

I could easily write code that processes `a` and calls `setattr` 5 times to accomplish this.  But I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the following code is very elegant but it works. It's a double `*apply` loop.
Quoting the question:

> I could easily write code that processes `a` and calls `setattr` 5 times to accomplish this. But I'm hoping there is a better way.

The problem is that the `name` in `setattr` must be a length 1 character string, so `setattr` will always have to be called 5 times. In the code below this is done in disguise of a double loop.

The example `data.table` comes from the 3rd `DT` in `help("setattr")`.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x1 = 1:3, y = 4:6, x3 = 7:9)
a <- list(x1=list(label='X1', units='mm'),
          x3=list(label='X3', comment='collected remotely', format='type 3'))

mapply(function(x, a){
  lapply(names(a), function(na) setattr(DT[[x]], na, a[[na]]))
}, names(a), a)

attributes(DT$x1)
#$label
#[1] "X1"
#
#$units
#[1] "mm"

attributes(DT$x3)
#$label
#[1] "X3"
#
#$comment
#[1] "collected remotely"
#
#$format
#[1] "type 3"
```

---

**Note.** In order to avoid the ugly output from the loops, wrap them in `invisible`:

```
invisible(
  mapply(function(x, a){
    lapply(names(a), function(na) setattr(DT[[x]], na, a[[na]]))
  }, names(a), a)
)
```

---

### Edit

The following code is simpler.

```
lapply(names(a), function(x){
  lapply(names(a[[x]]), function(y) setattr(DT[[x]], y, a[[x]][[y]]))
})
```

Comment: If you or anyone else wants an additional challenge: If one of the attributes is "class" and there is an existing class for a column, we would want to do `class(x) <- unique(c(class(x), newclass))`

Answer (score 2):

This may deviate too much from you desired output, but just to throw out an idea: because `setattr` accepts a `data.table`, an alternative may be to set attributes at the `data.table` level, as a named list pointing to the individual columns:

```
setattr(d, "all_attr", a)
str(d)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x1: int  1 2 3
# $ y : int  4 5 6
# $ x3: int  7 8 9
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
#   - attr(*, "all_attr")=List of 2
# ..$ x1:List of 2
# .. ..$ label: chr "X1"
# .. ..$ units: chr "mm"
# ..$ x3:List of 3
# .. ..$ label  : chr "X3"
# .. ..$ comment: chr "collected remotely"
# .. ..$ format : chr "type 3"
```

---

If you want the attributes set at the level of individual columns, and if you can live with attributes as a nested list, I think it may be enough to loop over the columns.

```
lapply(names(a), function(x) setattr(d[[x]], x, a[[x]]))
str(d)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x1: int  1 2 3
# ..- attr(*, "x1")=List of 2
# .. ..$ label: chr "X1"
# .. ..$ units: chr "mm"
# $ y : int  4 5 6
# $ x3: int  7 8 9
# ..- attr(*, "x3")=List of 3
# .. ..$ label  : chr "X3"
# .. ..$ comment: chr "collected remotely"
# .. ..$ format : chr "type 3"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x1 = 1:3, y = 4:6, x3 = 7:9)
```

Comment: With all the effort I've put in to the `Hmisc` package to deal with variable `label`s and `units`, I've sometimes thought that separating such subset-invariant attributes as you have done may be a better idea.   Good food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Frank! Perhaps you could specify/elaborate your requirements in your question as well, e.g. using the toy data from the answers? Cheers

Comment: This is a much different issue but there are occasions where attributes may best be kept as separate objects and not even placed as an "external" `data.table` attribute.  For example, I've sometimes thought that variable labels should be variable name-specific within one entire analysis script, no matter which data table a variable is coming from.  I would then define an object like `a` above and have various graphics and table making functions look for `label` and `units` in `a` to form axis labels and table row or column headings.